# Convert a little different multidimensional arrays in same multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using an API from a contributer for my hotel booking engine. Whenever i need some information from his system, i execute CURL and i get the response in XML. Then i apply `json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)), true)`
and i get the response in array. So far so good, but there is a specific problem. The returned XML for the same function doesn't have always the same format. It depends on the parameters of the request. I 'll use a specific example to make this clear.
When i need to get the availability of my room/rooms, i send a request with a range of days. There are 4 different situations here.

1. 1 room - 1 day
2. 1 room - multiple days
3. Multiple rooms - 1 day
4. Multiple rooms - Multiple days

In situation (1) the array is like this:[image]

In situation (2) the array is like this:
[image]

In situation (3) the array is like this:
[image]

In situation (4) the array is like this:
[image]

As you can see, if there is 1 room, there is no 0 key as an index and the information seems like "1 level up". Same situation for days. If you request for more than 1 day, then all days have their index (0, 1, 2 etc..).

The question is: **Is there a way to convert every response to the array like situation 4?**

I mean if there is 1 room, place it's information under RoomAvailability['0']. If there are more, place them like RoomAvailability['1'], RoomAvailability['2'] etc...
Same thing for the DayAvailability. If there is one one day place the day's information under DayAvailability['0']. Many days? DayAvailability['1'], DayAvailability['2'] etc... 
With this trouble the only thing i could do to check if there are many rooms was:

```
if (isset($response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability']['0'])) {
   //Do staff
}
```

But that's pretty bad! I don't want to waste time and conditions if there is 1 room or 50, 1 day or 30!

Any1 can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question because i found out what my problem is.
In this line `json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)), true)` if a node has children, the array is like `$array[0][something], $array[1][something]` etc... but if there is only one child the array goes like `$array[something]` without the 0 key! That was totally unexpected!

After a lot of search, it seems like there is no abstract and proper way to convert any XML to a php array, keep each node's attributes and keep the same structure as the XML was. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

I decided to use `SimpleXMLElement` [php.net link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), pretty simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a pre-check if they're array, and if not, encapsulate it in an array.

First do that for the main array (in this case the second RoomsAvailability)
an array

```
if(array_key_exists('@attributes', ($response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability']))
{
  $response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability'] = [$response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability']];
}
```

After that you need to run each room and do the same for the  days

```
foreach($response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability'] as &$item)
{
  if(array_key_exists('DayAvailability', $item))
  {
    $item = [$item];
  }
}
```

Full code:

```
// check if the base room availability is a single room, if it is convert into an array
if(array_key_exists('@attributes', ($response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability']))
{
  $response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability'] = [$response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability']];
}

// now do the same for all the days in rooms
foreach($response['RoomsAvailability']['RoomAvailability'] as &$item)
{
  if(array_key_exists('DayAvailability', $item))
  {
    $item = [$item];
  }
}

// now do you stuff
```

> **NOTICE**: on the `foreach`I've added an `&` at `&$item` so that the changes in the foreach do have effect outside of it